# how to implement linux query in perl?

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I use the following query on linux to get the server load:

```
w | head -n 1 | awk '{print $12}'
```

Now i want to run the query through a perl script and print the output in browser. How do i do that?

Comment: `system("w | head -n 1 | awk '{print $12}'")`

Comment: how do i capture its output??

Comment: you don't need the `head` , try `w | awk '{print $12;exit}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the output of a shell command simply by using backticks:

```
chomp( my $load = `w | head -n 1 | awk '{print \$12}'` );
```

The `$` has to be escaped, because otherwise Perl will try to interpolate a variable before sending the command.

`system()` is the preferred way of calling an external command if you *don't* need the output.

However, if you are writing more than a quick utility script, it is usually better to replace system commands with equivalent Perl code.  There are lots of modules available that replicate the functionality of common shell commands and tasks.

Answer (score 3):

The following spawns one process instead of four:

```
open(my $pipe, '-|', 'w') or die $!;
my $line = <$pipe>;
close($pipe);
my $load = (split ' ', $line)[11];
```

- `close($pipe)` closes the pipe which stops `w` from sending more output.
- `split ' ', EXPR` splits EXPR on whitespace.
- `(EXPR)[11]` gets the twelfth item return by EXPR.

Answer (score 0):

To run system commands in perl, please refer [this](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands).

Answer (score 0):

All that is necessary is

```
my $load = (split ' ', `w`, 13)[11];
```